# How is IIdentity identity implemented

Tags: c#, extension-methods, asp.net-identity

I have a question regarding the IIdentity identity, normally in the web app you can say:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.
```

And it has several properties which you can easily retrieve, very handy.

So i have 2 questions for this:

1) I'm working with ASP.NET Identity (not membership), but when i try to extend  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

```
public static int GetUserAge(this IIdentity identity){}
```

To import: IIdentity identity i have to use, using System.Security.Principal;, but is it in the same package as Microsoft.AspNet.Identity?

2) By default, the methods and properties, like User.Identity.Name / User.Identity.Id, / User.Identity.GerUserId() etc, how are they implemented? Does the implementation every time go to database to retrieve it? Or it saves in session or ...?

Because i would like to create an extension and work more or less the same way as by default ...

Comment: If i remember correctly. IIdentity is party of system.security.principal. The default implementation of IIdentity is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. So a class like Identity : IIdentity is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. The second question, i believe it depends on your memebership provider and where the user information is coming from. SqlAspnetMembershipProvider will run queries to get user information. If you are hard coding users in the web.config then i believe it loads it into memory when the application loads.

Comment: Yes, they come from database

Answer (score 0):

So AspNet.Identity is only adding extension methods which give syntactic sugar to hide casting IIdentity to a ClaimsIdentity and maps two claim types to helper method getters.

```
GetUserName() => ClaimTypes.Name
GetUserId() => ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier.
```

Comment: Not really an answer, because what i wanted to know how it gets it? I mean does it every time queues a database for that info or ...? i mean If on each page i'm going to do .Identity.GetUserId(), will it then every time go to database to get it and show ... meaning every time the user refereshes there will be a roundtrip to db

Comment: The user ID is stored in the claims for the identity so a round trip to the database is not required.

Comment: so if i want to make another extension, to for example retrieve a name, should i implement it also more or less the same way and store the user display name in a claim? And where are the claims stored?

Comment: The claims are generated from the database and stored in the login cookie.  So you can modify what claims are generated from your user via the ClaimsIdentityFactory and those will show up in the ClaimsIdentity